# take picture generated by QR CODE

Tags: jquery, sql

i'm going to use QR CODE and after generating picture i need to save this picture, the question is ,is that possible and how i can do that?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "take this picture", particularly in relation to [tag:sql]?

Comment: what did you try so far? show some of your code please.

Comment: The usual meaning of the expression "take a picture" involves a camera. I have the impression that you are using a JavaScript plugin to generate a QR code and you want to submit the generated picture to a server-side database but it's impossible to tell from your wording. Could you please edit the question, clarify what you mean and possibly share some relevant code?

Comment: i generated qrcode photo in javascript now i need to save this picture, name it and save this name in database . P.S i meant save picture

Comment: Thank you gays i solved the problem and posted how i did

Answer (score -1):

[image]

In HTML I wrote this script:

```
<input id="text" type="text" value="aa" style="width:80%" /><br />
<div id="qrcode" style="width:100px; height:100px; margin-top:15px;"></div>
<div id="append"></div>
```